# Using PHP AMQPConnection inside a thread

Tags: php, multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a PHP program where I connect to a Rabbit MQ server and retrieve messages. I have put this functionality inside a function:

```
function get_messages()
{
    $connection = new AMQPConnection();
    $connection->setLogin($rabbit_username);
    $connection->setPassword($rabbit_passwd);
    $connection->setHost($rabbit_host);

    while (!$connection->connect())
    {
            echo "## Trying to connect to Rabbit MQ...\n";
            sleep(1);
    }

    $amqpchn = new AMQPChannel($connection);
    $mq = new AMQPQueue($amqpchn);
    $mq->setName("myqueue");
    $mq->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE|AMQP_PASSIVE);
    $mq->declare();   // must declare then bind
    $mq->bind("my.exchange","my.routing");

    // do stuff
}
```

This works fine. However when I try to run the function get_messages() from inside a thread (just one thread), the code gets stuck at $connection->connect(). It cannot connect to the Rabbit server.

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried connecting to rabbitmq outside of the thread and passing it into the function?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do:    
    $connection = new AMQPConnection();
    $connection->setLogin($rabbit_username);
    $connection->setPassword($rabbit_passwd);
    $connection->setHost($rabbit_host);
outside the thread and passing it the $connection but it then said inside the thread that $conection was not connected.

Comment: did you call $connection->connect();?

Comment: yeah, but inside the thread I check if it is connected: $connection->isConnected()  but it says it is not. Very strange.

Comment: can you post some more code...?

Comment: Got it to work, my queue name was getting mangled goign into the thread - duh. Thanks a bunch for the feedback!